# Is there a way to decompose a polynomial $xy+f(x,y)$ into the product of two convergent power series $x+g(x,y)$ and $y+h(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose we have a polynomial $xy+f(x,y)$, where $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ whose the lowest degree term has degree at least 3. My question is, are we always able to decompose $xy+f(x,y)$ into the product of two convergent power series $x+g(x,y)$ and $y+h(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, where terms in $g$ and $h$ have order higher than 1?

I have no idea about the convergence of power series with two or more variables. Any solution or reference will be appreciated! Please also note that it's not enough to simply decompose $xy+f(x,y)$ formally into two $x+g(x,y)$ and $y+h(x,y)$. We also need the convergence of $g$ and $h$!

Comment: Any assumptions on $ g $ and $ h $?

Comment: So the question can we have $(x+h(x,y))(y+
g(x,y))=(xy+f(x,y))$ by expanding you get: $xy+xg+yh+gh = xy+f$ so $f=xg+yh+gh$; yes we can always have such decomposition.

Comment: @Bananach I really need $g$ and $h$ to be convergent, and I fogot to say that they consist of higher order terms

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Note that we can't expect $g$ and $h$ are polynomials since $f$ isn't necessarily an irreducible polynomial. Can you guarantee that $g$ and $h$ are convergent?

Comment: @TiWen if you knew one of $h$ or $g$, then by the relation I had given above you would know the other one. I don't see how you can know $h$ and $g$ without further information; it's like division algorithm. Well there's Weirestrauss divison theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem I assume you knew this theorem beforehand.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist I am asking "Is there a way to decompose..." I only need the existence of such $g$ and $h$. Some brilliant people may even want to prove this without construction,

Comment: Do they need to be convergent everywhere?

Comment: @Bananach Thank you for your reminder! It's enough to make them convergent in a neighborhood $(0,0)$. (It would be perfect if you can actually make it convergent on $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb C^2$...I dispute this)

Comment: Consider $f(x,y)=(x^3+y^3)/3$.  Then we can solve $xy+f(x,y)=0$ explicitly, and plot the solutions in $R^2$.  (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+y+%2B+(x%5E3%2By%5E3)%2F3%3D%3D0).   This suggests to me that it can't be factored with analytic functions...I think what you need (as a tag if nothing else) is not "multivariable calculus" but "algebraic geometry".

Comment: @MattF. Thank you! But why do you think the figure of the solutions suggests that it can't be factored with analytic functions?

Comment: Heuristic 1: the only factoring is the obvious factoring, achieved by solving the equation, which isn't analytic.  Heuristic 2:  the factors would correspond to the two arcs going through the origin, but multiplying them gives the wrong degree.  But if you want rigor, I would ask an algebraic geometer.

Comment: I think $h(x,y)=y^2/3-x^2y/18+y^3x/(2.3^3)-5x^3y^2/(8.3^4)...$ and $g(x,y)=x^2/3-xy^2/18+yx^3/(2.3^3)-5x^2y^3/(8.3^4)...$ satisfy $(x+h)(y+g)=xy+(x^3+y^3)/3$ and are convergent near zero.

Comment: @san, if you can prove that those converge, you're done.  Write $xy+f(x,y)$ as $px^3+qxy+ry^3$.  If p or r has constant coefficient of 0, the factorization is trivial.  So assume p,q,r have non-zero constant coefficients.  Then let $u =  3p^{2/3}q^{-1}r^{1/3}x, v = 3p^{1/3}q^{-1}r^{2/3}y$, so that $$px^3+qxy+ry^3 = \frac{q^3}{9pr}\left(uv + \frac{u^3+v^3}{3}\right).$$  Factor the right hand side as above, and then use the power series expansions for the powers of p,q,r to convert back to x's and y's.

Comment: I don't understand. What happens if for example $p=x s(x)$? How is the factorization trivial?

Comment: @san, you are right, I had mistakenly generalized from the case p=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: In Rick Miranda's book ["Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces"](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/bookstore/bookpromo?fn=20&item=GSM-5), Lemma 2.3 on page 68 gives an argument that this factorization is possible in terms of formal power series, and then says that "it is an easy exercise" to show that these actually converge. His factorization is not in any way uniquely specified, and the formal factorization is not unique and can certainly be made to diverge, so it is not quite clear what he had in mind. Here is an alternative proof using the implicit function theorem:

We first claim that there exists a local analytic function $y=x^2 z(x)$ whose graph is contained in the zero set of $F(x,y) = xy + f(x,y)=0$. In order to do so, we change variables to $(x,z)$ by $y=x^2 z$ and divide the equation by $x^3$ to get
$$
P(x,z) = \frac{F(x,x^2 z)}{x^3} = z + \frac{f(x,x^2 z)}{x^3} = 0.
$$
Since every term in $f$ has degree $\ge 3$, we know that $P(x,z)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $z$, and that $P(0,z) = z-a$ where $-a$ is the coefficient of $x^3$ in $f(x,y)$. By the implicit function theorem there exists a local analytic function $z(x)$ such that $P(x,z(x))=0$, with $z(0) = a$. Then $h(x) = x^2 z(x)$ is analytic with $F(x,h(x)) = 0$. This implies that for every fixed $x$, the polynomial $y \mapsto F(x,y)$ has a zero at $y=h(x)$, so it has a linear factor of $y-h(x)$, implying that the function
$$
G(x,y) = \frac{F(x,y)}{y-h(x)} = \frac{xy + f(x,y)}{y-x^2z(x)} = x+g(x,y)
$$
is actually analytic near $(0,0)$, with $g(x,y)$ containing only terms of degree $\ge 2$. This shows
$$
xy + f(x,y) = (y-h(x))(x+g(x,y))
$$
with both $g$ and $h$ containing only higher-order terms. Note that this type of factorization is unique (by the uniqueness part of the implicit function theorem.)

Note also that this factorization can be made more symmetric by observing that $F(x,y)$ also has a factor of the form $x-g(y)$, by the exact same argument as above with variables switched, so we can factor
$$
F(x,y) = xy + f(x,y) = (x-g(y))(y-h(x))u(x,y)
$$
with $g(0)=g'(0)=h(0)=h'(0)=0$ and $u(0,0)=1$ analytic near $(0,0)$. This shows that the zero set of $F$ is locally the union of the graphs given by $x=g(y)$ and $y=g(x)$ which intersect transversally.

ADDENDUM: The fact that $G(x,y)$ is analytic in both $x$ and $y$ follows from the Cauchy Integral Formula (and this must be a standard result, but I am not an expert in several complex variables.) Since $h(x) = O(x^2)$, we can find $r>0$ such that $|h(x)|<r$ for $|x|=r$. Then Cauchy's Integral Formula applied to the polynomial function $y \mapsto G(x,y)$ gives
$$
G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{G(x,\zeta)}{\zeta - y} \, d\zeta
$$
for all $|x|,|y|<r$. The function $x \mapsto G(x,\zeta) = \frac{F(x,\zeta)}{\zeta - h(x)}$ is analytic for all $|\zeta|=r$ since the denominator never vanishes on this circle, so $x \mapsto G(x,y)$ is analytic in $|x|<r$.

Comment: That should read "so it has a linear factor of y-y(x)", which means this needs a revision.  I would change the notation from y(x) to h(x), so that the corrected big equation will read $$H(x,y)=\frac{F(x,y)}{y-h(x)} = \frac{xy+f(x,y)}{y - x^2t(x)} = x+g(x,y).$$  Then I think the appropriately revised conclusion is correct.

Comment: @MattF.: Thanks for catching this mistake, I completely scrambled the variables there. I edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: @Mattf: Also changed the notation to make it a little more consistent, and following your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for finishing one of the arguments that I tried before and failed to complete!

Comment: why is $x+g(x,y)$ analytic at （0,0）? I know it is a polynomial in y. But why is it convergent in terms of x?

Comment: @TiWen: This is a result on removable singularities, and it follows from the Cauchy Integral Formula. I will add a short argument.